# How to set Welcomepage using onet.xml

Tags: publishing

I need to set Welcome Page url only using onet.xml
In this case OverView.aspx should be welcome page. This is what i found. But didnot work for me.

```
<WebFeatures>
<!-- Enable Publishing Feature -->
<Feature ID="94c94ca6-b32f-4da9-a9e3-1f3d343d7ecb" >
    <Properties>
        <Property Key="WelcomePageUrl" Value="$Resources:cmscore,List_Pages_UrlName;/OverView.aspx"/>
        </Properties>
</Feature>
```

Answer (score 1):

following code works for me.

```
<!-- Publishing feature -->
<Feature ID="22A9EF55-847B-4ff2-9346-694633FE4416">
<Properties xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<Property Key="WelcomePageUrl" Value="$Resources:cmscore,List_Pages_UrlName;/Default.aspx"/>
<Property Key="PagesListUrl" Value=""/>
<Property Key="AvailableWebTemplates" Value=""/>
<Property Key="AvailablePageLayouts" Value=""/>
<Property Key="SimplePublishing" Value="true" />
...
</Properties>
</Feature>
```

Comment: Thanks. but didnot work for me :(